# Can I say 11:30 as eleven and a half?

Tags: time

When we talk time, I know I can say eleven thirty or half-past eleven for 11:30. But how about eleven and a half? Is it correct?

Comment: You really can *say* almost anything, but this is not idiomatic.

Comment: Why not look up "telling time in English" before asking. Spanish: Las once y media. Portuguese: as onze e meia.

Comment: In colloquial British English, "Half eleven" - I don't think Americans say that. But not "eleven and a half".

Answer (score 3):

No. That is not a standard way of talking about time. Have you ever heard anyone use "eleven and a half" when talking about time?

When telling the time, "half past eleven", or "eleven thirty" is correct.

When describing a *duration* you can say "I was working for eleven and a half hours".

Comment: Thanks, I thought it wasn't, but I needed to make sure.

Comment: Have you learned any foreign languages? Would consider "Have you ever heard this phrasing" to be a helpful question if you had question about a foreign language you were learning?

Comment: @Accumulation - It’s also a fair question, though. (I learn about new phrases quite often while perusing ELL. Just because I’ve never heard it here in the US doesn’t mean it’s not commonly used somewhere like New Zealand.) The OP didn’t say whether this was heard somewhere, read somewhere, or just a curiosity.

Comment: Yes I have studied foreign languages. I ask "have you heard this phrasing" as a genuine question. Sometimes people have been told things by teachers who don't speak English well. Sometimes they have misunderstood a lesson. It is correct to say "eleven and a half hours" to describe a duration, so there is potential for confusion. Extra details could help me write a better answer.

Comment: @Lambie - English is not my first language, I live in Brazil and I teach English here. One of my students asked me this question. I was pretty sure this is not right, and I told him. I know that if I google "how to say the time in English", this phrase won't appear as an option, but I wanted to ask a native speaker in case there was any sort of exception.